# Customizing styles for Md Megamenu in Drupal 7

Tags: css, drupal-7, megamenu

I have a site and a staging site. I had to update some modules, so tested it on my staging site first. When updated the staging site, the megamenu styling got messed up becuase it is no longer pulling in two stylesheets. Anyway to update/import the css files from the frontend of Drupal? Or is this something I need to do in the backend.

I was looking in the files for the live (non-updated site), for the info file that held Stylesheets all [] = missingStylesheet.css, since after researching it seemed that is what calls/loads the stylesheets, so I can check the staging site had the same correct file, but I can't find it anywhere in the backend files for the live site.

The land of drupal is confusing, any idea how I can get either the missing styleseets loaded from the front end, or Where in the live site I should look to find where it calls the [missing] stylesheets?

My apologies for the image, just wanted to show that everything is identical except for the two missing stylesheets, that aren't showing up when you inspect the Staging site home page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you meant in:

> the info file that held Stylesheets all [] = missingStylesheet.css, since after researching it seemed that is what calls/loads the stylesheets

Never encountered anything like `missingStylesheet.css`.

Anyway there are two simpliest reasons why after updating module the css files went missing and I suggest this for start.

1. **Files was deleted from server.** Well sometimes module developers make mistakes and updated module dont work properly. Check on your server if inside `md_megamenu` module your missing css files exists `menu_styles/css/mm-base.css` and `menu_styles/css/mm-style1.css`. **If not** I suggest you to copy them back from live site and forget about problem. Proper way is to create patch for contibuted modules but I'll leave this topic. **If files exist on server or this solution didnt helped.** See point 2.
2. **Css files are not included to your page.** Even if they exists maybe the including part of code is missing. You can use `drupal_add_css` function to include css file [see here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7.x). In your situation it would be something like that: 

   `drupal_add_css( drupal_get_path('module', 'md_megamenu') . "/menu_styles/css/mm-base.css");`

   **In addition** function `drupal_get_path` return list of all css files that are queued to be included on given page, so you can investigate what files are currently added by simple dpm

   `$css = drupal_add_css( "/nonexistingcss.css");
   dpm($css,'$css');`

   Just remember that this snippet will return to you list of files queued at **current moment, and additional stylesheets might be queued after this code executes.**